# Laravel session data passing

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-4

I don't understand how my data is directed through session using `->with`.

For example I am doing a simple redirect with some data:

```
return Redirect::to('/event')->with('data', 'hello.');
```

Now, this code below works fine:

```
$data = Session::get('data');
echo $data; //it says hello
```

But this one NOT:

```
var_dump($_SESSION); //empty array
```

The `var_dump` gives me empty array, which means that session doesnt contain anything I guess. While the `Session::get()` has no problems with it. Why does that happen? Please explain it to me a little bit.

Comment: You use this `var_dump($_SESSION);` after `Session::get('data')` ?

Comment: I always do `var_dump` at the top of my page, so i can be sure it doesn't dissapear somewhere on my page.

Comment: Just because `->with` flash data to session only for the next request.

Comment: That's a good point, thank you. Anyway, I have even tried to `var_dump` before the doctype but it is still empty.

Comment: Even before the `doctype` you still inside the app ;). Please refer to Request lifecycle for more details. Good Luck.

Comment: which version of Laravel are you using ? 4.0 or 4.1 ?

Comment: @Moppo laravel 4.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For security reasons Laravel uses its own custom session handler which doesn't populate `$_SESSION` superglobals with your session variables, so to work with laravel session you should only use `Session` facade's methods

Comment: Laravel is creating file in storage_path()/sessions directory. Where is stored name of file? Cookie seems to hold some value, but it dont match any of file names in that directory